# Apache HttpClient 4.3 and x509 client certificate to authenticate

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, x509certificate, spring-ws

now I looking for solution regarding task how to rewrite deprecated solution for client side x509 certificate authentication via HttpComponentsMessageSender (not relevant).

For example, deprecated solution is:

```
    SSLSocketFactory lSchemeSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(this.keyStore, this.keyStorePassword);
    Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, lSchemeSocketFactory);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient)getHttpClient();
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
```

As new solution with CloseableHttpClient I am using:

```
    SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
            // this key store must contain the key/cert of the client
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    if (trustStore != null) {
        // this key store must contain the certs needed and trusted to verify the servers cert
        sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(trustStore);
    }

    SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();

    LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    // Create a registry of custom connection socket factories for supported
    // protocol schemes / https
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("https", sslsf)
            .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
            .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connPoolControl =
            new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
    setConnPoolControl(connPoolControl);
    getClientBuilder().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf);
```

I still get 403 forbidden from server. But when I use "deprecated" version of the solution, it works great. SSL certificate is signed Thawte.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Tomas, maybe it's too late, but I hope it will help others... 
There is the method, which I'm using to create CloseableHttpClient using Apache HttpClient 4.3:

```
public static CloseableHttpClient prepareClient() {
    try {           
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).useTLS().build();
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory);
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();
        HttpClientConnectionManager ccm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
        builder.setConnectionManager(ccm);
        return builder.build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Apache Foundation moved org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder, org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts and org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory to deprecated starting with 4.4 version, [There](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/deprecated-list.html) you can find Apache Client 4.5.2 API Depracated List. So, pervious method can be changed like this:

```
public static CloseableHttpClient prepareClient() {
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = 
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), 
                        new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory);
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = 
                RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();
        HttpClientConnectionManager ccm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
        builder.setConnectionManager(ccm);
        return builder.build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("couldn't create httpClient!! {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

[NoopHostnameVerifier](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/NoopHostnameVerifier.html)

> The NO_OP HostnameVerifier essentially turns hostname verification
>   off. This implementation is a no-op, and never throws the
>   SSLException.

If you need to verify hostname, you can use DefaultHostnameVerifier or you can implement your custom hostname verifier.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a keystore that containts the trusted CAs i.e. `trust.jks`. In this keystore you should put only the certificate of the server that your application is going to connect.

Then, you need a keystore for the identity of the server i.e. `identity.jks`. In this keystore you should store put the private key + certificate + CA chain under an alias (a name) that your application is going to use to authenticate itself with the server.

Then you could build the `HttpClient` like this:

```
public static HttpClient getHttpClient() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {

    KeyStore identityKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    identityKeyStore.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("identity.jks"), "identity_password".toCharArray());

    KeyStore trustKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    trustKeyStore.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("trust.jks"), "trust_password".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
            .custom()
            // load identity keystore
            .loadKeyMaterial(identityKeyStore, "identity_password".toCharArray(), new PrivateKeyStrategy() {
                @Override
                public String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket) {
                    return "identity_alias";
                }
            })
            // load trust keystore
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustKeyStore, null)
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"},
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();
}
```

To build the `identity.jks`, you need the CAs chain, the public key and the private key:

```
$1 = mycustomidentity

# make the keycert bundle for pkcs12 keystore
cat intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem \
    intermediate/certs/$1.cert.pem \
    intermediate/private/$1.key.pem \
    > intermediate/keycerts/$1.full-chain.keycert.pem

# generate the pkcs12 keystore with the alias of the server url
openssl pkcs12 -export \
    -in intermediate/keycerts/$1.full-chain.keycert.pem \
    -out intermediate/pkcs12s/$1.full-chain.p12 \
    -name $1 \
    -noiter -nomaciter

# .p12 to .jks
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $1.full-chain.p12 \
    -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias $1 \
    -destkeystore identity.jks -deststoretype jks \
    -deststorepass identity_password -destalias identity_alias
```

For the `trust.jks` file you only need the certificate of the server (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/2692914 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886248/2692914), there is no problem in changing the alias:

```
# .crt, .cer into a .jks
keytool -import -alias trust_alias -file server_certificate.crt \
    -keystore trust.jks
```

Comment: What is DnieUtils here?

Comment: The name of the class. In this case to get the classloader that will load the resource

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for HttpClient 4.4+ *(updated @Daniyar code for 4.4+)*

```
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;

public static CloseableHttpClient createApacheHttp4ClientWithClientCertAuth() {
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                new DefaultHostnameVerifier());

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory);
        builder.setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry));

        return builder.build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        return null;
    }
}
```