# httpclient https post method

Tags: java, httpclient, canvas-lms

I want to Create a USER in Canvas LMS using their REST API.
The certificate / ssl config / cacerts are all at right locations.

I am able to POST a http post request to the url using CURL it works fine.

I created a simple java class using httpclient and when i am trying to post the value it is not working...The response code is sometimes 400, 403.

I am sending the Headers Authorization: Bearer AccessToken
Still no luck.....

can anyone help me on how to post a https post request through httpclient.

regards

Comment: Maybe try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375121/mutual-authentication-with-x509-certificates-using-httpclient-4-0-1

Comment: I got ssl certificate for my server. and its fine now