# Trouble connecting Jira and HP ALM synchronizer with HTTPS

Tags: ssl, jira, hp-alm

I do not manage to connect my JIRA server and my QC via the HP ALM Synchronizer.

I get the following error message on the ALM QC Synchronizer when I try to connect it to the jira server:

> handling exception: java.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal
>   alert : handshake failure.

Version of Jira : 6.3.15 running on Apache Tomcat 7
Version of ALM QC synchronizer : 12.50.1

I have already imported the SSL certificate of the Jira server on the keystore of the java running the ALM QC synchronizer. Anyone has any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the root cause of the problem.
ALM QC Synchronizer is running on an old version of Java (java 1.6.0.17).

My Jira server was running on Tomcat 7.
I had to enable the TLSv1 and SSLv2Hello on the Tomcat 7 side of my Jira server.
This is well explained in 
[this Tomcat 7 issue : Tomcat7getting-sslv2hello-is-disabled-error-when-trying-to-make-client-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488667/tomcat-7-getting-sslv2hello-is-disabled-error-when-trying-to-make-client-server)