# SSL Handshake Debugging not working any more with Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22

Tags: debugging, ssl, https, tomcat9

I have to debug a SSL Handshake on Tomcat (OS: MS Windows), so I followed the instructions found in the web an enabled it with the following line in setenv.bat:

> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.debug=ssl"

With Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21 everything works fine, when I opened the page with my browser I can see the handshake on the commandline.

With Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22 I only can see which certificates are beeing loaded on startup but after then when I call the server via browser no more output is generated on the commandline.

The only difference I could find out is that the Protocolhandler is different between those versions:

- Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21 uses ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8083"]
- Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M22 uses ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8083"]

Is there anything I have to do additional to enable ssl handshake-debugging?

This is my Connector configured in server.xml:

```
    <Connector port="8083" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="<Path to Keystore>"
               keystorePass="<KeystorePW>" />
```

Comment: In your catalina log, you should see a line containing "finished startup in" with the time it took to start the process. Can you check this first ? Then we know if the start is finished.

Comment: Yes I can see that line.

org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 453 ms

Server acts and responds completely normal.

Comment: did you try running M22 with the M21's server.xml (or even copying the whole conf directory) ?

Comment: Yes, I completely adjust all settings (settings.xml, logging.properties, setenv.bat, etc.) so that the only difference between these two Tomcats is the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try forcing JSSE use by adding `sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"` in your Connector . For any reason it's detecting APR and trying to use OpenSSL which is not working. You might fill a bug or ask the Tomcat users mailing-list, but 9.0.0 was a development release.

Comment: Thank you, this helps indeed!